# What determines how node names are displayed in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a graph that is structured like so:

Region - hasDivision -> Division - hasSalesRep -> Sales Rep - hasCustomer -> Customer

This works pretty well until the very end. The problem is that all the customer nodes have the same names as the sales reps they're associated with.

[image]

Each of these grey 'Christian ----' nodes has an actual customer name attached to it as a property, and that's what should be displayed, but it isn't.

The mysterious thing to me is that I'm using the same code, the same labeling scheme, and the same property scheme I've used for region, division, and sales rep, all of which has worked fine.

I've tried various experiments and things have only been weirder. If I only load in 'customer_name' as a property, the nodes are grey blobs with no labels (but they do have customer_names attached). If I switch 'customer_name' and 'rep_name' when loading in the customer_dim.csv, all nodes have correct customer names attached to them. If I change rep_name to rep_nam (removing the 'e'), everything goes back to grey blobs with no labels.

What's going on?

Here's loading the region

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///location_dim.csv' AS region
WITH 
    region.REGION_NM AS REGION_NM
MERGE (n:region {reg: REGION_NM})
RETURN n
```

Here's loading the division.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///location_dim.csv' AS division
WITH 
    division.REGION_NM AS REGION_NM,
    division.DIVISION_NM AS DIVISION_NM,
    division.STATE_PROVINCE_CD AS STATE_PROVINCE_CD
MERGE (n:division {div: DIVISION_NM, reg: REGION_NM, state: STATE_PROVINCE_CD})
RETURN n
```

Here's loading sales rep.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sales_rep_dim.csv' AS row
WITH 
    row.SALES_REP_KEY AS SALES_REP_KEY,
    row.SALES_REP_NM AS SALES_REP_NM,
    row.JOB_DESC AS JOB_DESC,
    row.WORK_STATE_PROVINCE_CD AS WORK_STATE_PROVINCE_CD
MERGE (n:Sales_rep {sales_rep_key:SALES_REP_KEY, rep_name: SALES_REP_NM, job:JOB_DESC, state:WORK_STATE_PROVINCE_CD})
RETURN n
```

Here's customers

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///customer_dim.csv' AS customer
WITH
    customer.CUSTOMER_NM AS CUSTOMER_NM,
    customer.SALES_REP_NM AS SALES_REP_NM
MERGE (n:customer {customer_name:CUSTOMER_NM, rep_name:SALES_REP_NM})
RETURN n
```

And here's me creating all the relationships

```
MATCH (a:region), (b:division), (c:Sales_rep), (d:customer)
WHERE a.reg = b.reg AND b.state = c.state AND c.rep_name = d.rep_name
MERGE (a)-[:hasDiv]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:hasRep]->(c)
MERGE (c)-[:hasCustomer]->(d)
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

I've tried removing and reordering the properties, but I keep running into the same issues.

Comment: What does MATCH (c:customer) RETURN c.customer_name,c.rep_name LIMIT 5 return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a specific property value, you have to configure it on the browser. :

[image]